# JavaFX saving changes in data form on close/on hide of a secondary window

Tags: javafx, controller, save, exit

I am trying to make my application close changes made in a data form when the user clicks the [X] button.  In the application the user can double click a row in a TableView to edit the row.  If changes are made and the user clicks [X], then I want to prompt the user to confirm changes, then save the changes.  The below code is what I have so far.

Main Controller:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(decorator);     scene.getStylesheets().add(LawnCareSystem.class.getResource("/resources/css/style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                EditCustomerController.saveChanges();
            }
        });
        stage.show();
```

Secondary Controller:

```
public static void saveChanges(CustomerRow cr){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        sb.append("update Customers");

        if(!cFName.getText().equals(cr.getFirstName())){
            sb.append(" set FirstName = '"+cFName.getText()+"',");
        }
        if(!cLName.getText().equals(cr.getLastName())){
            sb.append(" set LastName = '"+cLName.getText()+"',");
        }
        if(!cEMail.getText().equals(cr.getEmail())){
            sb.append(" set Email = '"+cEMail.getText()+"',");
        }
        if(!cPhoneNumber.getText().equals(cr.getPhoneNumber())){
            sb.append(" set PhoneNumber = '"+cPhoneNumber.getText()+"',");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        sb.append(" where Customer_ID = "+cCustomerID);
        . . .
        . .
        .
    }
```

The problem is that saveChanges must be made static in order to access it in the EventHandler.  There must be a better solution and I am hoping you guys can point me in that direction.

Comment: Why must it be made static? "Static" has nothing to do with accessibility: it is about scope. Make it non-static and call it using the controller *instance*, not the controller class.

Comment: How do I call it from the controller instance? Can I get access to the stage from the controller?

Comment: No, I meant call it using a reference to the controller instance: i.e. `EditCustomerController controller = loader.getController();` and then `controller.saveChanges();`, where `loader` is the `FXMLLoader` instance that was used to load the FXML file for which `EditCustomerController` is the controller class.

Comment: I am receiving a null pointer exception when I run the code after getting the controller in the EventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `saveChanges` method non-static, and call it using a reference to the controller, instead of the controller class. You can get a reference to the controller from the FXML loader.

You didn't show the code for loading the FXML, but assuming you do it right before you create the `Scene` and the `Stage`, you would do:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClasS().getResource("/path/to/fxml"));
Parent decorator = loader.load();
EditCustomerController editCustomerController = loader.getController();

Scene scene = new Scene(decorator);     scene.getStylesheets().add(LawnCareSystem.class.getResource("/resources/css/style.css").toExternalForm());
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        editCustomerController.saveChanges();
    }
});
stage.show();
```

and then of course in the controller, just remove the `static` keyword from the `saveChanges()` method:

```
public void saveChanges(CustomerRow cr){

    // ...
}
```